# Result of my Post Request is an Auth Token for the user. I want to show this token in a TextView in the app, but the textview is not updating

Tags: android, kotlin

//The function for retrieving the token --> this is working!

object Constants {

//ophalen token van de user (request met username en password, fetchedTokenModel en apiService

```
fun getFetchedToken(username: String, password: String): String{

        var fetchedToken: String = ""  // wordt in deze functie als return uitkomst gegeven, ophalen in mainactivity

        // Create Retrofit
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8000")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        // Create Service
        val service = retrofit.create(APIService.APIService::class.java)

        // Create JSON using JSONObject
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("username", username)   //deze krijgen van het loginscherm app, wordt nu meegegeven in mainactivity
        jsonObject.put("password", password)   //deze krijgen van het loginscherm app


        // Convert JSONObject to String
        val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()

        // Create RequestBody ( We're not using any converter, like GsonConverter, MoshiConverter e.t.c, that's why we use RequestBody )
        val requestBody = jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // Do the POST request and get response
            val response = service.loginUser(requestBody)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val items = response.body()
                    if (items != null) {
                        println("items: ${items.key}")
                        val fetchedToken = items.key.toString()
                        println("fetchedToken as String: ${fetchedToken}")



                    }
                } else {

                    Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())

                }
            }
        }
            println("fetchted token voor return: ${fetchedToken}")
            return fetchedToken
    }

}
```

//My mainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val getFetchedTokenUser = Constants.getFetchedToken(username = "test", password = "test123")
    println("val fetchedtoken: ${getFetchedTokenUser}")
    text_view_result.text = getFetchedTokenUser





}
```

}

//here i want the textview beeing updated with the returned token, but its empty. Something is telling me it has to do with coroutine. Iam a starter so i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The result of getFetchedToken() takes time, and when you set textView the state is loading.

1. make getFetchedToken() suspend.
2. remove CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {} from getFetchedToken function.
3. run below code in your activity

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
      val getFetchedTokenUser = Constants.getFetchedToken(username = "test", 
      password = "test123")
      println("val fetchedtoken: ${getFetchedTokenUser}")

      withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
           text_view_result.text = getFetchedTokenUser
      }

      }

   }
   ```

Comment: When i put the whole function in MainActivity.kt it works fine ?. The function is in a an seperate file, the " val getfetchedToken" is overwritten with "", thats why i get nothing. The fetchedToken is in the return statement, but it gives me "". I cant figure it out

Comment: you set fetchedToken=" " in getFetchedToken(), then launch a CoroutineScope and change fetchedToken in network response, but before it changes, return fetchedToken is called.

Comment: yes i saw that but where else can i put the return with the fetchtedToken

Comment: you should make your function suspend, and call it in the coroutineScope